# How to close thread while thread is suspended in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I trying to close my form while thread is suspended but i got this error : `Thread is suspended; attempting to abort.`

If the thread is running and i Click Button Close it fine.

Here my code :

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    t1.Abort()

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

I want to close the form even though the thread is suspended or not suspended.

Comment: Don't ever suspend threads.  It is evil.

Comment: And don't .Abort threads, full of gotcha's.

Comment: You can set IsBackground() to True for your Thread which will allow it to be killed it automatically when the application shuts down.  But I agree with the previous posts that you shouldn't be using Suspend() or Abort()!

Comment: As others have said, [do not suspend or abort threads](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/16/do-not-suspend-or-abort-threads/).

Comment: Use Tasks instead if you can.  The have the ability to be canceled which is really nice.  Seriously check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern for sleeping a thread and how to 'abort' it.  Note that the .WaitOne can take an argument that works like a Thread.Sleep.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'start a thread
    If IsNothing(somethrd) Then
        somethrd = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf test)
        somethrd.IsBackground = True
        somethrd.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'stop
    stopsomethrd = True
    somethrdwait.Set()
    somethrd.Join()
    Debug.WriteLine("end")
End Sub

Dim somethrd As Threading.Thread
Dim somethrdwait As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)
Dim stopsomethrd As Boolean

Private Sub test()
    Do
        'your code
        somethrdwait.WaitOne() 'suspend thread
        If stopsomethrd Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```